# Redirect to login page when session expires + silex

Tags: php, session, symfony, redirect, silex

I want to redirect to my login page when my session is expired. What happens now:

When you are for example logged in and at the dashboard, you will see you're username in the right top corner. But when you don't do anything for 2 hours or so and then refresh you get an error that it's impossible to access an attribute 'username' of NULL. This comes because you're logged out... But how can I redirect to the login page when my session expires?

I know how I can increase the expire time but I don't know how I can redirect ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check if username is set in your session

```
/* NATIVE PHP */
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}

/* Symfony Syntax - thanks @Touki */
if (!$request->getSession()->get('username')) {
    return new RedirectResponse('login', 301);
}
```

Comment: And I just paste this in my general layout view?

Comment: Just don't. Use the symfony's request abstraction instead. `$request->getSession()->get('username')` and `return new RedirectResponse('login', 301)`

Comment: You can place it at [$app->before()](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html#before-middleware).

Comment: Thanks, but the 'username' attr doesn't exist. When I dump my $request->getSession() I get this: http://pastebin.com/7XQbJJ08  
What should I use?